# Cant find value in sqlite database

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

I am doing simple login/signup coding in android using sqlite for data storage , DB creation and data insertion is fine but i cant find value when user log into the account, when I open DB in sqlite browser data is present there but in android cursor couldnot find it

```
public  String serachContact(String srchn,String srchp)
{

    db=getReadableDatabase();
    String query="Select email,pswrd from ContactsInfo" ; 
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    String u ; // used for fetching email address
    int c=0;
    String p="not found"; 

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    do {
        u = cursor.getString(0);
        if (u.equals(srchn)) {
            p = cursor.getString(1); // get password for matching 
            break;
        }

    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());
     return p;

}
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is bit messy and you haven't mentioned what error(s) you are getting.

Change your code as like below code,use `getWritableDatabase` method.

```
      String email;    
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {                   
               email = cursor.getString(0);
               Log.d("email is ", email);
               if (email.equals(srchn)) {
                    return cursor.getString(1); 
                    break;
               }                   
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
```

At last close the cursor in finally method using `cursor.close()` to prevent any memory leak.

You can also check whether you are setting up the sqlite correctly,here are two tutorials [tutorial 1](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and [tutorial 2.](http://web.archive.org/web/20160101220015/http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial)

Comment: When I run my app on emulator it works fine and find value successfully but when I run the same app on my mobile device it cannot search value 
whats the issue ? can you help me? @Neel